# access pdo from php via console

Tags: php, pdo

I installed easyphp on win7 and added the php directory to my path.
When I run `php -i`, I get:

```
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers =>
```

whereas, when querying php via apache, I get:

```
PDO drivers mysql, sqlite, sqlite2
```

How could I get these drivers into the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CGI typically has a different `php.ini` file than CLI. You can find out which .ini file PHP is using with [`php_ini_loaded_file()`](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php). If you copy the contents of the CGI config (in Debian it's located in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`) to your CLI ini file, it might do the trick.

Comment: Where would php be looking for such?

Comment: Ah, it seems I have to put there...
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => C:\Windows

Comment: I added a PHPRC environment variable pointing to C:\PROGRA~2\EASYPH~1.0\apache. This seems to have done the trick. Thanks!